# Ubuntu no internet connection

Tags: ubuntu, internet, ubuntu-10.04, networking, internet-connection

For some reason, Ubuntu 10.04 thinks I do not have a connection to the internet, when yesterday I did.  I have Windows XP installed via dual OS boot, and the internet connection works perfectly.

What's going on?

Comment: Wired or wireless?

Comment: Wired, I've checked all the connection, when I didn't need to as it works perfectly well when using XP partition on this computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try running these commands on Ubuntu to see if they clear up the problem.

This command should reset the whole networking system on your system and automatically renew your IP Address and fetch DNS servers and the such from your router.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

These two commands are helpful if you ever run into problems with your ethernet connection. The drop and restart your wired connection.

```
sudo ifdown eth0
sudo ifup eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

was it a clean install you did yesterday? if so perhaps the kernel has updated during post-install updates.if so you might have to compile your drivers for your network interface against the new kernel. check akseli's answer to see if you have in interface functioning, if you dont you should download latest tarball module for your network card, ./configure make && make install